# Div with background image spilling out of parent div in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image

I understand there's a gazillion questions on this issue but none of the solutions on any of them seem to work for me. This is what my markup looks like:

```
<div class="immersion-div">
    <div class="immersion-div-image"></div>
</div>
```

As you see, it's a fairly straightforward setup with one div containing another. The parent div is styled to adapt its height to the device screen resolution using media queries. Here's how the two divs are styled:

**Parent div**:

```
@media (min-width: 2000px) { .immersion-div { height: 1307px; } }
@media (max-width: 1999px) and (min-width: 1401px) { .immersion-div { height: 1000px; } }
@media (max-width: 1400px) and (min-width: 750px) { .immersion-div { height: 500px; } }
@media (max-width: 749px) and (min-width: 300px) { .immersion-div { height: 300px; } }
@media (max-width: 299px) { .immersion-div { height: 136px; } }
```

**Child div (with the image background)**:

```
.immersion-div-image {
    background: url(../../bootstrap/img/homepage/spanish_immersion.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The image serving as the background is 2880px by 900px (although that should be inconsequential in this scenario) and the resolution of the screen on which I tested this is 1366px wide. Per the defined media queries, the height of parent div should evaluate to 500px since the screen falls in the 750px-1400px category. However, on Internet Explorer, the div seems to render with a height of 1000px! This issue is only affecting IE whereas all other browsers are rendering the divs fine. What could be the problem? Before anyone suggests using `background-size: contain`, I must admit I tried it and it messes up the aspect ratio leaving a blank band at the bottom of the div which is why I don't want to go that route. Besides, I want to understand why `cover` wouldn't work on IE when it does just fine on all other browsers.

Just in case it helps, the site in question is peppyburro.com and the affected divs are on the last green image on the home page.